# Inverse derivation of differential equation $f(x)=\frac{dy}{dx} +\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, inverse-function

The following function is given:
$$ f(x)=\frac{dy}{dx} +\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}$$

I'am looking for the inverse function in Leibniz writing style. Here is my attempt:

$$ f^{-1}(x)=\frac{dx}{dy} -\frac{d^2x}{dy^2} {\Biggl(\frac{dy}{dx}}\Biggl)^3  -\frac{d^3x}{dy^3} {\Biggl(\frac{dy}{dx}}\Biggl)^4+3{\Biggl(\frac{d^2x}{dy^2}}\Biggl)^2  {\Biggl(\frac{dy}{dx}}\Biggl)^5 $$

Is this correct?

Comment: How did you get this expression for $f^{-1}$?

Comment: Are you sure you want to compute the inverse? Or the derivative of the inverse? Because the latter is usually easier.

Comment: @lisyarus:  This is a mixture of trying on my own and various internet sources. Especially with the terms dx/dy with the inverse I am unsure...

Comment: @Miguel: Yes, it should be the inverse. This is exemplary of a bigger problem.

Comment: Do you assume that $y=f(x)$? If not, in what sense is the inverse used, in what relation is $f^{-1}(y)$ to $f(x)$? You seem to want to change the independent variable from $x$ to $y$, could you add some intermediary steps for getting to the last equation?

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann Sorry, failure.

Comment: If you remain with the Leibniz symbolism, then you have coordinates $x,y,z$ with $z=f(x)$ and $y=g(x)$, where, changing the symbolic, $f(x)=g'(x)+g''(x)+g'''(x)$. Now you try to express $f^{-1}$, that is, $x$ as a function of $z$, somehow using $g^{-1}$ and its derivatives, ... ?